# Nexus emulator screen doesnt show mvn android:deploy result

Tags: java, android, maven

I am trying to deploy on android-emulator, a sample maven project "helloflashlight" ( https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples)
My maven build completes successfully and mvn android:deploy prints below message:

```
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:deploy (default-cli) @ helloflashlight ---
[INFO] Waiting for initial device list from the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter not set, using all attached devices
[INFO] Emulator emulator-5554_First-Nexus_unknown_sdk found.
[INFO] emulator-5554_First-Nexus_unknown_sdk :   Successfully installed C:\git\samples\helloflashlight\target\helloflashlight.apk to emulator-5554_First-Nexus_u
nknown_sdk
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Looking at the HelloFlashlight (main-activity) class, I should be able to see multiple buttons(like greenButton,redButton) on screen, which on click, change the background color.
However, I don't see any change in nexus emulator screen. It is still showing Charging 50%(attached image). Any clues on what could be possibly wrong??

[image]

Comment: What is the app supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to show buttons of different colors which when clicked change the color. it is standard sample app: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples

Answer (score 1):

That's the lockscreen of the emulator. As with any other Android device, you would click and drag the lock icon to the side to unlock the device. If the app is not currently on the screen, you would then click on the All Apps button, and inside of there should be the name of your app, and click on it to launch it.